# Unable to update spacy to newer version 3 in conda enviroment

Tags: python, conda, spacy-3

I have been trying to update spacy to the new version in conda environment. I have not been successful though I have used the below command `conda update spacy=3.0`
and

```bash
(base) hadi@notebook:~$ conda install -c conda-forge spacy=3.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

Comment: Did the flexible solve run to completion? What did it show? There is usually a bunch more output after this when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks. I got answer issue was spacy has not released version 3 for conda.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost exactly the same problem, but I was using PyCall in Julia.

The solution for me was to remove spacy, clean conda and then manually add conda-forge as a channel and then reinstall spacy.

```
conda remove spacy
conda clean
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install spacy
```

explicitly adding the channel may be what actually fixed the problem, but I am not sure.

Comment: This worked for me without using `conda clean`.